# Do these simple T-SQL Update statements update identically?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following example, assuming that NULL values are not allowed.

Are these 2 update statements:

Query #1:

```
UPDATE #R12
SET SOURCE_NAME = DEFLT.SOURCE_NAME       
FROM R12_MLR_REBATE_GL_STRING_DEFLT DEFLT
WHERE #R12.PAYMT_TY    = DEFLT.PAYMT_TY
  AND #R12.AMOUNT_TYPE = DEFLT.AMOUNT_TYPE
  AND #R12.COMPANY     <> @BNKER_COMPANY
  AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND  = 'N'
```

Query #2:

```
UPDATE #R12
SET SOURCE_NAME = DEFLT.SOURCE_NAME       
FROM R12_MLR_REBATE_GL_STRING_DEFLT DEFLT
WHERE #R12.PAYMT_TY    = DEFLT.PAYMT_TY
  AND #R12.AMOUNT_TYPE = DEFLT.AMOUNT_TYPE
  AND #R12.COMPANY     = @BNKER_COMPANY
  AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND  = 'Y'
```

equivalent to this one update statement?

```
UPDATE #R12
SET SOURCE_NAME = DEFLT.SOURCE_NAME
FROM R12_MLR_REBATE_GL_STRING_DEFLT DEFLT
WHERE #R12.PAYMT_TY    = DEFLT.PAYMT_TY
  AND #R12.AMOUNT_TYPE = DEFLT.AMOUNT_TYPE
  AND ((#R12.COMPANY <> @BNKER_COMPANY AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND = 'N')      
       OR (#R12.COMPANY = @BNKER_COMPANY AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND = 'Y')  
)
```

Do I get the same behavior if I use a JOIN syntax? By this I mean that if I run them both, in that order, that they will provide the same eventual output as running the 'unified' version.

```
UPDATE R12
SET SOURCE_NAME = DEFLT.SOURCE_NAME
FROM #R12 R12
INNER JOIN R12_MLR_REBATE_GL_STRING_DEFLT DEFLT ON R12.PAYMT_TY    = DEFLT.PAYMT_TY
                                                AND R12.AMOUNT_TYPE = DEFLT.AMOUNT_TYPE
                                                AND ((R12.COMPANY <> @BNKER_COMPANY AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND = 'N')
                                                      OR (R12.COMPANY = @BNKER_COMPANY AND DEFLT.BNKER_IND = 'Y'))
```

I'm experiencing some paranoia and would feel better with a second opinion.

Comment: Please define what you mean by 'two statements'.  Does it mean  if you run them both, in that order, that they will provide the same eventual output as running the 'unified' version?

Comment: No. Even if `BNKER_IND` is a char, it has either 256 or 144K+ options (depending on the actual type). A `char` isn't a boolean. And depending on the collation, `Y` may not be equal to `y` either. Use the correct type for each field

Comment: And `NULL` isn't equal even to null, which means that if `R12.COMPANY` is null both `R12.COMPANY <> @BNKER_COMPANY` and `R12.COMPANY = @BNKER_COMPANY` will fail

Comment: With our database settings, case and trailing spaces don't matter in comparisons

Comment: @Ivan you still need to account for NULLs. The execution plans for the queries may be different as well. A `char(1)` doesn't have just two values. Even if the statistics show there are just 2 values, the query optimizer may decide to *ignore* any indexes on that field because they aren't selective enough - that's why `bit` columns can't be indexed

Comment: I checked my schema and I see that none of the columns allow NULL. I do realize that the Update would fail if it did allow nulls but i feel like, if NULL values were allowed, that the unified version would fail the same as the original. I updated the question to indicate to assume that NULL values were not allowed.

Comment: Assuming `BNKER_IND` and `COMPANY` are not indexed, and are not nullable, and `BNKER_IND` is constrained to `N` or `Y`, no it won't make a difference. Otherwise you are risking either incorrect results or not using indexes

Comment: BNKER_IND may be Y, N, or X. Why would that matter? Why would the presence of an index matter other than performance?

Comment: Because the `OR` will probably prevent `BNKER_IND` or `COMPANY` working as index lookup column. Now that I think about it, in this instance the existence of other options won't make any difference in this respect. What will affect things is what indexing you have in place on the two tables. Regards using join syntax: the other syntax is effectively a non-obvious `CROSS JOIN` with `WHERE`, and explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax should really be favored instead.